# Parse 2 different websites with JSON information in WP7

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I have been stuck on this problem for longer than I care to admit. Let me explain what I want to do. I have a website that has a bunch of auctions and their data stored as a JSON file. I have already figured out how to parse JSON data using JSON.net's deserializer. Now, what I need to do is to take the data that I parse from that auction listing and then get more detailed information from another website using the item id# in each of the auctions. Here is what I have so far:

```
public AuctionSearch()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
    proxy.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(get_auction_info);
    proxy.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com/auctions/"));
}

void get_auction_info(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Stream stream = e.Result;
    StreamReader sr = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuctionListing>(result);
}
```

Here is the classes that I am currently using to store the auction information:

```
public class AuctionListing
{
    public long auctionID { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public long itemID { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
    public long bid { get; set; }
    public long buyout { get; set; }
    public long quantity { get; set; }
    public string timeLeft { get; set; }
}
```

Now, here is my problem. I am trying to use the item ID # that I get from that JSON parse and get the item name from another website that will display the item name and a bunch of other information about the item. The URL would be something like http://www.newexample.com/i/%itemID%/json and I would then have to parse the information. Once I have parsed it, I am having a problem getting the name to go with the rest of the item information for each auction. I have basically the same functions as above, but parsing to a different class (of course). I hope I have given enough information about what I am trying to do for someone to help me out. If I need to post my full code up here, I can, but it is quite long. I think my problem is something to do with how the OpenReadAsync works, but I am not for sure. Let me know if you guys have any other questions.

**Clarification**

I understand how to get the item name. My problem is that I want to store all of the information from both parses. Below is my source code. I will explain what happens after it.

```
(continuation of the code from above)
void get_auction_info(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    (stuff from above)

    for (int i = 0; i < root[i].Length; i++)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(auction_information);
        client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.newexample.com/i/" + root[i].itemID + "/json"));

        TextBlock tb = new Textblock();
        tb.Text = (
                    "Auction ID #: " + root[i].auctionID +
                    "\nItem ID: " + root[i].itemID + "\n\n"
                  );
        tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
        TextPanel.Children.Add(tb);
    }
}

void aucton_information(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Stream stream = e.Result;
    StreamReader itemStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string theResult = itemStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

    var secondRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuctionInfo>(theResult);

    stream.Close();
    itemStreamReader.Close();
}
```

Now, my problem is this. Once I call the second URL from the auction_information OpenReadAsync, it doesn't work the way I would expect it to. What I would like to do is to be able to get the item name from the given itemID, and then set it as the variable for the itemName. I don't understand how I am going to return the item name that I just got from the second JSON parse and set it as the value of the itemID in the root object from the first JSON call. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear to me but is it that you want to have your itemID in the uri?

you can just do this in the same way you did the auctions:

```
public ItemSearch() 
{ 
    InitializeComponent(); 
    WebClient proxy = new WebClient(); 
    proxy.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(get_item_info); 
    proxy.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com/i/" + auction.itemID.ToString() + "/json")); 
}
```

if the problem is getting the itemID in the callback that is used to parse the specific item you can use the eventargs e to get the uri and filter the id from it

Comment: Clarified my original question, so I hope that might help.